# Как в строке одновременно заменить "." на "!" и "!" на "."

Tags: java, строки, replace

Я решил попробовать заменить все точки в строке на ! и одновременно наоборот( т.е ".!.!" -> "!.!."), но не очень понимаю , как это сделать и возможно ли это вообще.

Пробовал сделать это через `.replace()`

Comment: "Пробовал сделать это через .replace()" - и?

Comment: И ничего не вышло.

Через replace("a","b");

Comment: Идём по строке посимвольно и каждый символ добавляем в новую строку. При этом, если символ не точка и не восклицательный знак — добавляем его как есть, если точка — добавляем вместо нее восклицательный знак и наоборот.

Comment: А, все было настолько просто. Спасибо

Comment: Если нужно именно через replace — меняем все восклицательные знаки на какой-то символ, которого в строке быть не может, условно — на #, меняем все точки на восклицательные знаки, меняем все # на точки. Но это решение хрупкое и можно применять только если есть какой-то символ, которого 100% нее бывает в строке

Comment: Ещё одно решение — замена с помощью регулярки в один проход — ищем `[!.]` а замену выбираем с помощью функции. Не знаю если ли такая возможность в java, наверняка есть, потому что есть много в каких языках, в т.ч. в C#, JS

Comment: @АндрейNOP, есть с 9й джавы: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866755/4928642.

Answer (score 3):

*нормальный алгоритм с преобразованием в массив char'ов, циклом и созданием строки*:

```java
var str = "a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...";
var arr = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == '!') {
        arr[i] = '.';
    } else if (arr[i] == '.') {
        arr[i] = '!';
    }
}
var rep = new String(arr);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(rep);
```

Результат:

```
a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...
a!b!c!!d!!.!!e..!!!...f!!!!..!...!!!
```

---

Если нужно преобразовывать не два, а больше символов, можно использовать `switch` вместо `if / else if`:

```java
// Java 12+
static String replacer(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) return str;

    var arr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = switch(arr[i]) {
            case '.' -> '!';
            case '!' -> '.';
            default  -> arr[i];
        };
    }
    return new String(arr);
}
```

или карту символов со стримами :)

```java
static final Map<Character, Character> MAP = Map.of(
    '.', '!',
    '!', '.'
);

static String convert(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) return str;
    
    return str.chars() // IntStream
        .mapToObj(c -> MAP.getOrDefault((char) c, (char) c)) // Stream<Character>
        .collect(Collector.of( // идиома для преобразования Stream<Character> в String
            StringBuilder::new, (bld, c) -> bld.append(c.charValue()), 
            StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::toString
        )); 
}
```

Comment: О, switch expression - круто)))

Answer (score 2):

Нормальный вариант с регулярками:
https://ideone.com/02Z0vQ

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    var str = "a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...";

    var res = Pattern.compile("[.!]").matcher(str)
              .replaceAll(m -> m.group().equals(".") ? "!" : ".");
    
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

```
a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...
a!b!c!!d!!.!!e..!!!...f!!!!..!...!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, например, через стримы

допустим, `s` - это строка, тогда новая строка:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        .limit(s.length())
        .map(x -> s.charAt(x) == '.' ? '!' : (s.charAt(x) == '!' ? '.' : s.charAt(x)))
        .map(x -> x.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 1):

Также предложу свой вариант:

String s = ".!.!.!...!";

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\.", ",").replaceAll("!", ".").replaceAll(",", "!");
```

P. S в первом replaceAll, там два слеша

Comment: А если в строке есть запятая, то что получится?

Comment: @Эникейщик могу предложить UUID сгенерировать :/

Comment: @USER1111 могу предложить написать на python в одну строку. ''.join(ch if ch not in ('.', '!') elif ch == '.' '!' else '.' for ch in s)

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич так у нас тут java, получается O:-)

Comment: @Эникейщик, то у меня есть способ. Интересно, нормальный алгоритм с преобразованием в массив char'ов, циклом и созданием строки кто-нибудь напишет, или всем похимичить охото?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, в js ещё короче: `s.replace(/[.!]/g, m => "!."[+(m==="!")])` :)

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется попридумывать алгоритмы:
https://ideone.com/Y2BLPt

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    var str = "a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...";

    var res = str
      .replaceAll("\\.", "..")
      .replaceAll("!", ".!")
      .replaceAll("\\.\\.", "!")
      .replaceAll("\\.!", ".")
    ;
    
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

```
a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...
a!b!c!!d!!.!!e..!!!...f!!!!..!...!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое извращение с регулярками, асимптотика квадратичная:
https://ideone.com/prUYqn

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    var str = "a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...";
    var res = (str + ".!").replaceAll("..$|\\.(?=.*?(!))|!(?=.*(\\.))", "$1$2");
    
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(res);
  }
}
```

```
a.b.c..d..!..e!!...!!!f....!!.!!!...
a!b!c!!d!!.!!e..!!!...f!!!!..!...!!!
```